# OpenText Case360 REST API

Tags: case, workflow, opentext

How to find the list of RESTful services in OpenText case360

Am trying to get the RESTful services in case360

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any direct way to find Rest services as per my knowledge you can look into Sonora.webservices package.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I figured it out
We can get the details using WADL ,

Get WADL definition from
 http:///sonora/rest?_wadl and save this as Case360_REST_API_v1.wadl file.
Import this 
Case360_REST_API_v1.wadl in post man you will get the list of webservice.